# Task Queues Socket time out exception google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, facebook-graph-api

i am calling data collection program using task Queues in GAE. 
Using http URL it will collect data from fb and load it to cloud storage .
By using Task Queue in GAE it should process for 10 minitues as mentioned in Google documents .

it is giving following error.
    java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Timeout while fetching URL: https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=select+message,post_id,created_time,actor_id,attachment,comments,created_time,impressions,likes,message_tags,place,share_count+from+stream+where+source_id+in(select+page_id+from+page+where+username='*')&access_token=***********************